# kendo scheduler datasource required fields

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to show some events in a kendo scheduler but they do not show. What are the required fields that the datasourse needs? I have id, title, start and end which is what the documentation says.

here is my code:

```
        dataSource: {
            batch: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/schedule/appointments_read",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                parameterMap: function(options, operation)
                {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models)
                    {
                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "id",
                        fields: {
                            id: { from: "Id", type: "number" },
                            title: { from: "Title", },
                            start: { from: "Start", type: "date"},
                            end: { from: "End", type: "date"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

here is the json that I return:

```
{"Data":
[{"Id":1,"Title":"AAA","Start":"\/Date(1414767600000)\/","End":"\/Date(1414771200000)\/"},
 {"Id":2,"Title":"BBB","Start":"\/Date(1414771200000)\/","End":"\/Date(1414774800000)\/"},
 {"Id":3,"Title":"CCC","Start":"\/Date(1414774800000)\/","End":"\/Date(1414778400000)\/"},
 {"Id":4,"Title":"DDD","Start":"\/Date(1414778400000)\/","End":"\/Date(1414782000000)\/"}],
 "Total":4,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null}
```

those are four one hour long appointments at 8:00, 9:00, 10:00 and 11:00 on the current day.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Required fields are listed in the [SchedulerEvent API](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/schedulerevent).